# How to Split Complex String in java and how to sum values?

Tags: java, string, substring

My String is like this

```
String myString= "3:2 2:26 1:11 8:4 4:25";
```

In this string I want to add all numbers occurring  after ":" (and before the next whiteSpace). In this case Result is 2+26+11+4+25 = 68. How can I achieve this using Reg Expression?

My effort is:

```
if(a.contains(":")){
    for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) {
        if(a.contains(":")){
            int indexOFColan= a.indexOf(":");
            //System.out.println("indexOFColan:"+indexOFColan);
            //int indexWhiteSpace = a.indexOf(" ");
            String   firstValue = String.valueOf(a.charAt((indexOFColan+1)));
            System.out.println("FinalString:"+firstValue);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a dump on stackoverflow, why don't you? Please make an effort before you post. If you've made an effort, post it explaining why it failed.

Comment: You need to at least show you tried.

Comment: You can use `String#split` and split twice, first on white space and then on colon. It is simple if you just try.

Comment: I would: 1) Use a regular expression replace (e.g. String.replaceAll) to change all "A:B" into "B", 2) Use String.split to turn the resulting string into sequence of strings, and 3) Iterate over the sequence, using Integer.parseInt on each element and keep a running total. Good luck!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : dedumped (aka edited) OPs question. Hopefully, it's more readable now.

Comment: You can just write it all on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

```
    String in = "3:2 2:26 1:11 8:4 4:25";
    String[] split = in.split(" ");
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    {
        try {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(split[i].split(":")[1]);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Input not a number");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks John, if well and good if explain same through Regular Expressions. sorry i don't how to use Reg Ex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to purely use regular expressions, the required expression is `"\\d+:(\\d+)\\s*"` (as a Java String).

Use `Pattern#matcher` method with `find()` to get the numbers you need:

```
int getSumofNumbersInComplexString(String my_string) {
    int sum = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+:(\\d+)\\s*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(my_string);
    while (m.find())
         sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    return sum;
}
```

The above code should work for a string in the format you've specified. There are many other SO questions on regex matching, in case you want more details of how this works.

Comment: sorry i don't how to use Reg Ex.

Comment: Not working The Result is 3:2  2:26   so it was string throwing NumberFormat Exception.

Comment: You need to get `group(1)` to get the number. `group(0)` contains the entire match, `group(n)`, for n > 0, contains the n'th bracket in the regular expression. The regex I suggested is working fine, as you can test [on this Java regex page](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).